# Any Help Watch app extension no matching provisioning profile found?

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, provisioning-profile

Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NMBm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqox6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have faced this problem before.  You will need to create three separate provisioning profiles:

1) The provisioning profile that you already have for your actual app.

2) Provisioning profile for the WatchKit target.

3) Provisioning profile for the WatchKit Extension.

The Bundle Identifier is different for your app, watch kit app, and watch kit extension.  You will use that Bundle Identifier when creating these three different provisioning profiles.

Make sure that when you go to your Build Settings for each of these three targets, under Code Signing select the specific Provisioning Profile that goes with your Bundle Identifier (not Automatic).